C2065 for stb_image in source file
I have 3 files: main.cpp, static_mesh.hpp, and static_mesh.cpp.
main.cpp includes static_mesh.hpp; static_mesh.hpp includes tiny_gltf.h which includes stb_image; static_mesh.cpp includes static_mesh.hpp.
main.cpp defines STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION and STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATIONbefore including static_mesh.hpp.
The problem is that i get errors because the compiler doesn't recognize the type stbi_uc and the function stbi_load_from_memory() in static_mesh.cpp.
Here's the code section for those files:
main.cpp:
...
#define STB_IMAGE_IMPLEMENTATION
#define STB_IMAGE_WRITE_IMPLEMENTATION

#define TINYGLTF_IMPLEMENTATION

#include "static_mesh.hpp"
...

static_mesh.hpp:
#pragma once

#include <tiny_gltf.h>
...

static_mesh.cpp:
#include <static_mesh.hpp>
...
int x, y;
int  channels_in_file;
stbi_uc* data = stbi_load_from_memory(v_ptr, bufferview.byteLength, &x, &y, &channels_in_file, image.component);
...

EDIT: the errors i get:
static_mesh.cpp(71,3): error C2065: 'stbi_uc': undeclared identifier
static_mesh.cpp(71,12): error C2065: 'data': undeclared identifier
static_mesh.cpp(71,19): error C3861: 'stbi_load_from_memory': identifier not found
static_mesh.cpp(79,104): error C2065: 'data': undeclared identifier

UPDATE: I ended up using this workaround: define TINYGLTF_NO_INCLUDE_STB_IMAGE and including it by myself.

Please [edit] your question to include the full error message(s) as text verbatim.  Have you #include'd the relevant STB headers etc. in static_mesh.cpp (either directly or indirectly)?

Hi, i just edited the question.
The stb headers are #include'd in tiny_gltf.h

I guess we still need a bit more context on your include order and content of static_mesh files. However, as a wild guess, you may try defining TINYGLTF_NO_INCLUDE_STB_IMAGE and include stb_image explicitly by yourself.

@MrOnlineCoder Thank you, defining TINYGLTF_NO_INCLUDE_STB_IMAGE and including stb_image by myself worked very well!
